# a href with # not working on mobile, only desktop

Tags: jquery, href, shortcode, hashref

I created a shortcode on Wordpress to display a button

the html output is

```
<a class="button" href="/about-page">About Page</a>
```

However when I put /#solutions in the href tag

```
<a class="feedzai-button" href="/#solutions">Explore Our Solutions</a>
```

it only works on desktop (it takes me down to the div with id="solutions"). On mobile, it doesn't take me down to the section, it seems to just refresh the page.

Any idea why this could be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried removing the '/'?  (Just `"#solutions"` is correct for navigating to an anchor on the current page)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/about-page#solutions`?

Comment: I did try just #solutions and it still has the same issue.
#solutions is on the same page.

The first a tag example was just a demonstration of what I am doing linking to other pages instead of a div